# how to make pointer to non-member-function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

if  i have for example class A which contains the functions:

```
//this is in A.h
friend const A operator+ (const A& a,const A& b);
friend const A operator* (const A& a,const A& b);
```

which is a global (for my understanding). this function implemented in A.cpp.

now, i have class B which also contains the functions, and the member:

```
//this is in B.h
friend const B operator+ (const B& a,const B& b);
friend const B operator* (const B& a,const B& b);
A _a;
```

instead of using two seperate methods, i want to create single method in B.h:

```
static const B Calc(const B&, const B&, funcP);
```

which implemented in B.cpp and funcP is typedef to the pointer to the function above:

```
typedef const A (*funcP) ( const A& a, const A& b);
```

but when i tried to call Calc(..) inside the function i get this error: 
"unresolved overloaded function type". i call it this way:

```
friend const B operator+ (const B& a,const B& b){
    ...
    return B::Calc(a,b, &operator+);
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't show that a `const B&` is in any way related to a `const A&`.

Comment: Please post complete code. Given the problems you are having it is impossible to way what is wrong without seeing more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloaded functions are  usually resolved based on the types of their arguments. When you make a pointer to a function this isn't possible so you have to use the address-of operator in a context that is unambiguous.

A cast is one way to achieve this.

```
static_cast<funcP>(&operator+)
```

Comment: i tried this but it give me error: invalid static_cast from type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to type ‘const NewDouble (*)(const NewDouble&, const NewDouble&)’

Comment: @or.nomore: I thought you said that `funcP` was a typedef for `const A (*)(const A&, const A&)`. What's `NewDouble`?

Comment: NewDouble is my A, sorry for the mix

Comment: but i want to use the operator+ of class A

Comment: Do you declare `const A operator+(const A &, const A &)` anywhere other than as a friend of `A`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. It's ugly, error-prone, and hard to understand and maintain.

This is what templates were invented for:

```
template< typename T >
static T Calc(const T& lhs, const T&, funcP rhs)
{
  return lhs + rhs;
}
```

(Note that I removed the `const` from the function's return type. Top-level `const` on non-referencing types makes no sense.)

Comment: sbi: `const` is perfectly find and often encouraged on function return types. It only makes no difference if the return type is of non-class object type.

Comment: but i don't realy understand how it can help me. do you mean turning class B to template calss?

Comment: @or.nomore: I didn't turn `B` into a class template, but `Calc` into a function template. It can now be instantiated with both `A` and `B`, and automatically picks up the right overload of `operator+`.

Comment: @sbi: but the T is always of type B

Comment: @or.nomore: Then why would you ever want to use `operator+(A,A)`??

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Could you explain?  What's the advantage?  Clients could always create non-`const` copies anyway, no?  The only case I can think of where it'd matter is in restricting anonymous objects (e.g. `Calc(...).foo()` wouldn't work if `foo()` isn't `const`, although `T(Calc(...)).foo()` would be fine).

Answer (score 0):

"which is a global (for my understanding)."

not for microsoft c at least 
"A friend function defined in a class is not supposed to be treated as if it were defined and declared in the global namespace scope" from ms visual c++ help